# contextDestroyed never called when Tomcat is shutdown in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I'm facing this issue where whenever I shutdown my Tomcat 8.0 on Eclipse, contextDestroyed on my ServletContextListener class is never called, but contextInitialized runs normally when I startup Tomcat. I'm using Servlet 3.1 version. Code:

```
@WebListener
public class ListenerContexto implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
         System.out.println("ListenerContexto FINALIZADO"); 
    }

    //Run this before web application is started
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
         System.out.println("ListenerContexto INICIADO");   
    }
}
```

On TOMCAT startup, I get "ListenerContexto INICIADO" on console. But when TOMCAT is shutdown, nothing shows on console.

Comment: How *exactly* are you starting and stopping Tomcat?

Comment: Directly through Eclipse Start and Stop button. An odd thing I discovered is that if I just hit the button stop it will produce no log at all, like a process kill. But if I click on the only tomcat set up server and click the button stop then it will produce the log as expected. I don't know if the stop button is supposed to have this behavior